# Supplemental .config File

Tags: 2010, development, feature, web-config

I wish to make a change to the web.config file. I know you can do this by using a supplemental config file. I know that the file needs to be coppied to `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\CONFIG`.

Does it need to be coppied on every server? Is it possible to automate the deployment of this file in a wsp?

Once the file has been ditrubuted I need to run stsadm -o copyappbincontent on each server to recreate the web.config file. To confirm if I add a new server I will not need to do this?

**Edit**

I am tring to add the following to the web.config

```
<add name="MySPXmlContentMapProvider" siteMapFile="myxml.sitemap" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPXmlContentMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
```

This was provided in answer [Cross Site Collection Navigation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21445/cross-site-collection-navigation)

**Edit 2**
[how-to-add-assemblies-into-gac-web-applications-bin-folder-using-wsps-created-using-visual-studio-2010](http://girishm.blog.com/2010/10/19/how-to-add-assemblies-into-gac-web-applications-bin-folder-using-wsps-created-using-visual-studio-2010s-sharepoint-projects-2/) shows how you can add a dll. In visual studios I can under  advance in the Manifest Tempalte I can add:

```
<RootFiles>
    <RootFile Location="CONFIG\webconfig.myname.xml" />
</RootFiles>
```

When I go to deploy the project I get:

> Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Error: Cannot find
>   this file specified in the manifest file: CONFIG\webconfig.myname.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2010 you can add Mapped folders which will deploy any file you want to any folder within SharePointRoot on every server.